# tradingview strategy pine script: How can i open a position at the open of the daily bar?

Tags: pine-script

How can I open a position at the open of the current daily bar? Entry condition for example, if open of the bar higher than previous close(after gap immediately). Thanks

I tried `calc_on_every_tick=true` but it opens a position on the next bar not the one I need.